# How do you say [noun] "for you"?

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to denote that an object is "for" someone. For example, "I bought a gift for you."

"I bought a gift" is easy enough.

> ぼくはおみやげをかいます。

However, I'm not sure about the "for you" part. あなたに doesn't seem to make much sense. Should I say あなたのおみやげをかいます。? Google Translate alternatively gives me あなたのためにおみやげ。Is this correct?

Comment: `"I bought a gift" is easy enough. ぼくはおみやげをかいます。` かいます should be かいました ("bought" is past tense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > "I bought a gift for you."

The text style answer for an exam is either
あなたにおみやげを買いました, or
あなたのためにおみやげを買いました。

> I'm not sure about the "for you" part. あなたに doesn't seem to make much sense.
>   Should I say あなたのおみやげをかいます。? Google Translate alternatively gives me あなたのためにおみやげ。Is this correct?

あなたのおみやげをかいました doesn't say 'for', but it just says 'your souvenir.'

Don't worry about it, we normally say
うちの子**に**本を買いました。[a little special occasion]
うちの子**のために**本を買いました。[a big event]
うちの子**の**本を買いました。[an ordinary everyday life event]

Answer (score 3):

You can just say　買ってあげました。 (the あげました。 gives the meaning that it was done for the other part.